# autoMirrored attribute is not working in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use the following back arrow in compose activity

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:autoMirrored="true"
android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">
<path
    android:fillColor="@android:color/white"
    android:pathData="M19,11H7.83l4.88,-4.88c0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.03 0,-1.42 -0.39,-0.39 -1.02,-0.39 -1.41,0l-6.59,6.59c-0.39,0.39 -0.39,1.02 0,1.41l6.59,6.59c0.39,0.39 1.02,0.39 1.41,0 0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.02 0,-1.41L7.83,13H19c0.55,0 1,-0.45 1,-1s-0.45,-1 -1,-1z" />
```

the problem is that the icon is not reverse direction when the app language change (RTL) even after using `android:autoMirrored="true"`

here's the UI code

```
Icon(
            imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_round_arrow_back_24),
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.White
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

That was reported as [a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/185760237) a couple of months ago. You might want to chime in there with your example (and bonus points for including a full project to reproduce the problem!).

Comment: Update: this was fixed and release on 1.2.0-alpha06: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.2.0-alpha06